# Opening my app by clicking on an external link?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Basically I want my app to show up in the list of the apps that pop up when you click on a link on android. Once the user chooses my app to open the link, I want it to be set as the content of a EditText. Any ideas of how I may do that?

Comment: You want to handle a particular link or all web links?

Comment: Try using [app-links](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing) and [deeplinks](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) in android

Comment: I want to handle all the links. For any link that is opened in any other app, I want the user to have the possibility to choose my app as the one to open the link with

Comment: If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother : https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Answer (score 0):

Should help

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Register intent filter inside activity in manifest. This is small example

```
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
<data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this as Android documentation says:

> To enable Google to crawl your app content and allow users to enter
>   your app from search results, you must add intent filters for the
>   relevant activities in your app manifest. These intent filters allow
>   deep linking to the content in any of your activities. For example,
>   the user might click on a deep link to view a page within a shopping
>   app that describes a product offering that the user is searching for.

To do this you need to add an intent filter in your Manifest with action, data and category attributes:

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="example"
          android:host="gizmos" />
```

You can read more about deep linking in [developers.android](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Correct me if i'm mistaken, but doing so my app would only open I click on certain links, not all of them. I want the users to be able to choose my app for any link, exactly like browser apps.

Comment: Yeah by using deep-linking you can do it. please  learn how to integrate deep-linking in android app.@Beter